# Use Get-Member for reflection

Tags: .net, reflection, powershell, watin

I'd basically like to use reflection in Powershell, and after dynamically finding the methods I'd like to invoke using standard powershell commands, I ended up with a MemberDefinition object and not much clue as to how to invoke it. I'm not positive I can, so if you have experience you can just say not to do it this way. I know I can drop into the Assembly namespace, but didn't know if I could do something like this:

```
$method = $ie | get-member -type method | ? { $_.name -eq 'span' }
invoke-member $ie $method
```

The `$method` variable is of type [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.memberdefinition%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), is this even possible?

Thanks, Matthew

Comment: make sure to check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/12/indirectly-invoking-methods-via-variablenames.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're pretty familiar with .NET, why not just drop down and use reflection directly?

```
PS> $d = Get-Date
PS> $t = $d.GetType()
PS> $t.InvokeMember("ToUniversalTime", "Public,InvokeMethod,Instance", $null, $d, $null)

Saturday, March 31, 2012 3:10:51 AM
```

Comment: I didn't know about InvokeMember :)  I figured there must be a better option than what I did, but mainly just gave an answer that I knew would work as a 'fall back' in case others wise in the way of the force didn't get a chance to respond. :)

Comment: Ok, yeah, thanks - I felt like there was a 'scriptier' way to do reflection -- passing strings to InvokeMember is going to get me what I'm after.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, you can always do it 'old-fashioned' reflection (mentioning just in case that's not clear).

For instance:

```
# get some object
$proc = get-process | select -first 1

# get its type and pick a method
$method = $proc.gettype().getmethods() | ?{ $_.name -eq 'tostring' }

# invoke
$method.Invoke($proc, $null)
```

Comment: @KeithHill: definitely!  Thanks for teaching me about InvokeMember :)

Comment: +1 for the link to _Indirectly Invoking Methods Via Variablenames_ - I think that was what I was originally thinking, but you and Keith demonstrated reflection doesn't haven't to be cumbersome in PS.